# Load component css when component render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I have component A and component B.

**component A.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './A.css'

export default class A extends React.Component {
   ....
}
```

**component B.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './B.css'

export default class B extends React.Component {
   ....
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import A from './A'
import B from './B'

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/A' component={A}/>
        <Route exact path='/B' component={B}/>
      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I visit /A it load a.css and b.css and vice versa. Is there way to render respective components CSS only when component is rendered on its route?

Comment: It sounds like you have different rules with the same selector in those components, and loading both CSS files overwrites some of the rules in one of them? Is that the actual problem you're having?

Comment: yes, addition I don't want to load component B css when Component A render.

Comment: Regarding the CSS issue, you can add a class to your main wrapping element: `<div className="compA">...</div>`, then put `.compA` in front of all your CSS selectors.

Comment: Is there any way around without changing classname? 
I found this way but not sure it is right?

render() {
    import('./SampleComponent.css');
}

Comment: Just try it out then. It's a good thing anyway if your questions already contains attempts you made on your own.

Comment: I am wondering what is best way practice.

Comment: Do you find any way to do that?

Comment: render() { import('./SampleComponent.css'); ---> This solution looks not working in react 18 and webpack 4... any idea about alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

In such case, you can make use of [styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) for component-specific styling.