# Load Component's CSS only When Component is Rendered in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, css-loader

There are two components wherein only one component will be rendered at a time conditionally. Every component has its respective CSS file which gets loaded inside the component using **import** statement, i.e. `import 'Header.css'`.

The problem is, even if one component is rendered, I could see both CSS files in the page Header.
Is there any way to avoid loading unused /(unrendered) components?

*Note 1: Can't use `module css` due to a technical reason as it needs entire app refactoring*

*Note 2: Found a couple of similar questions in SO but none of them have proper answers.*

[Load component css when component render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192217/load-component-css-when-component-render)

[Load a component's CSS only if it is rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61018410/load-a-components-css-only-if-it-is-rendered)

The below question has an accepted answer but the solution seems not working in `react 18` with `Webpack 4` :

[React: Load component's CSS only when component is rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560806/react-load-components-css-only-when-component-is-rendered)